# Using Multiple sheets run time error 91

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am very new to VBA but have been working on my knowledge to help my team increase their efficiency by creating simple macros in excel.  I am having some issues with this code and hope that you could help me figure it out.

I am trying to grab particular information from different worksheets and collect it all into the same sheet.  The macro needs to be quite robust as other users edit the sheet and make calculations.

Also open to any other suggestions for improving my code too.

Thank you for your help in advanced!

```
'For updating spreadsheet to QUOTE

Sub main()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Decalring worksheets
Dim wsO As Worksheet ' Ostendo
Set wsO = Sheets("Ostendo Import")

Dim wsP As Worksheet ' project costing
Set wsP = Sheets("Project Costing")

Dim wsH As Worksheet ' ostendo help
Set wsH = Sheets("Ostendo Help")

'finding the end of the row
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = wsO.UsedRange.Rows.Count


'Find the position of all values
Dim i As Integer

Dim Vfind(9) As String
Dim rngFound(9) As Range
Dim rngStart(9) As Range

Vfind(0) = "ITEMCODE"
Vfind(1) = "ITEMDESCRIPTION"
Vfind(2) = "SOURCEDBY"
Vfind(3) = "STDSELLPRICE"
Vfind(4) = "STDBUYPRICE"
Vfind(5) = "AVERAGECOST"
Vfind(6) = "PRIMARYSUPPLIER"
Vfind(7) = "JOBNOTES"
Vfind(8) = "ADDITIONALFIELD_1"
Vfind(9) = "ADDITIONALFIELD_3"

For i = 0 To 9

    Set rngStart(i) = wsO.Rows(2).Find(Vfind(i))
    Set rngFound(i) = rngStart(i).Offset(1, 0)

Next i

 'updating each ostendo field and updating it for QUOTING

 Dim j As Integer
 Dim strFind As String

'Inputing item code [0]
j = 0
strFind = "Item Code"
rngFound(j).Value = wsP.Rows(8).Find(strFind).Offset(1, 0)

'Updating Item Discription [1]
j = 1
strFind = "Item Discription"
rngFound(j).Value = wsH.Rows(4).Find(strFind).Offset(1, 0) 'ISSUE HERE RUN TIME ERROR 91  PLEASE HELP

'updating sourced by [2]
j = 2
rngFound(j).Value = "Assembly"

'updating standard sell price [3]
j = 3
strFind = "Adjusted Price"
rngFound(j).Value = wsP.Rows(8).Find(strFind).Offset(1, 0)

'updating COST for items without an assmebly (RAW FEATURES) [4]
j = 4
rngFound(j).ClearContents

'updating COST for items with an assembly (QUOTING COST) [5]
j = 5
strFind = "Total Light Cost"
rngFound(j).Value = wsP.Rows(8).Find(strFind).Offset(1, 0)

'updating Supplier [6]
'j = 6
'rngFind(j).ClearContents

'Updating Job Notes [7] Code to be Updated at a later date
j = 7
rngFound(j).Value = "Overall Dimensions: " & wsH.Rows(4).Find("Overall Dimentions: [H:W:D] or [DIA:D]").Offset(1, 0) & Chr(10) & "Finish: " & wsH.Rows(4).Find("Finish:").Offset(1, 0) & Chr(10) & "Light: " & wsH.Rows(4).Find("Light:").Offset(1, 0) & Chr(10) & "Driver: " & wsH.Rows(4).Find("Driver:").Offset(1, 0) & Chr(10) & "Dimming: " & wsH.Rows(4).Find("Dimming:").Offset(1, 0) & Chr(10) & "Features: " & wsH.Rows(4).Find("Features:").Offset(1, 0)


'updating supplier [8]
j = 8
strFind = "Supplier Code"
rngFound(j).ClearContents


'updating supplier code
j = 9
'strFind = "Supplier"
rngFound(j).ClearContents


'autofill loop
Dim k As Integer

For k = 0 To 8
rngFound(k).AutoFill Destination:=wsO.Range(rngFound(k), Cells(lastRow, rngFound(k).Column)), Type:=xlFillValues

Next k


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I think if people are going to be able to help you will need to be more specific about what the issues are. What is the desired behavior and what is happening instead? I guess from the title: you get a run time error 91. Does it say at what line?

Comment: Thank you @JeremyKahan for replying.  I have labelled the piece of code that is having the issue in the code.  Obviously not well enough.  It is where J = 1.  I think it is an issue with refering to different worksheets but I am unsure.

Comment: Could it be a spelling error, so the find fails? You have Discription. Did you mean Description?

Comment: Because then you would get back Nothing and doing Nothing.Offset causes the runtime error. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Comment: @JeremyKahan Spelling will be the end of me.  OMG.  Now I have a different error but I think I can fix that one.  Thank you.

Comment: You bet. Take care because a bit later you have "dimentions" where you mean "dimensions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out the error was searching for "Item Discription" instead of "Item Description". Then the .find call returned Nothing, and doing a .Offset on Nothing gave the runtime error. Fixing the spelling resolved it.
To get greater clarity and avoid the run time error, consider doing something like:

```
DIM c as range
c=wsH.Rows(4).Find(strFind)
if c Is Nothing Then
'give some error message about strFind not found
Else
    rngFound(j).Value=c.Offset(1, 0)
End If
```

but probably make a sub() of it to avoid repeating yourself.

Also, it is a style thing for sure, but I'm not convinced j or strfind are doing much for you as opposed to popping in the values directly.

Comment: The Sub idea is great.  I will give that ago.